# "improper alphabetic constant" with hyperref and bidi packages

Tags: xetex, hyperref, bidi

I'm getting an "improper alphabetic constant" error in xelatex which appears to be due to an interaction between the bidi and hyperref packages, when I redefine the \section cmd.  Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bidi} %Must be loaded after hyperref pkg
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{\RL{foo}}
\RL{bar}
\end{document}
```

It's important that the text \RL{bar} be the first non-whitespace after the \section{}, otherwise the error is not triggered.

I've checked the suggested "Similar Questions," and don't see anything quite like this.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think, you need to pass `unicode` option to `hyperref` package with XeTeX engine. So with the following example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bidi} %Must be loaded after hyperref pkg
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{\RL{foo}}
\RL{bar}
\end{document}
```

I get no error (using Updated TeXLive 2012) but one related warning which is due to the use of `\RL` macro inside `\section`:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\RL' on input line 9.
```

For details see page 19 of `hyperref` manual, under **Replacement macros** subsubsection.

To get rid off this warning, you can change your example into:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bidi} %Must be loaded after hyperref pkg
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{\texorpdfstring{\RL{foo}}{foo}}
\RL{bar}
\end{document}
```

and if you do not like `\texorpdfstring`, you can try:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bidi} %Must be loaded after hyperref pkg
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{}}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
\let\RL\@firstofone
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{\RL{foo}}
\RL{bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Odd, I had tried it without the [unicode] arg to hyperref first (and re-tried that just now), but I get the same error.  I'm running the TexLive 2011 version, I must have missed the 2012 update!

Comment: Thanks for the fixes--both work with 2011, although I'm now in the process of updating our installation to 2012, so maybe I won't need them :-).

Comment: We updated to the 2012 version, but I still get my original error msg ("improper alphabetic constant"), rather than the one you get about '\RL' not being allowed.  I guess you have some files that have been updated since TeXLive 2012 came out.  Can you explain the effect of omitting the \RL command (which IIUC is what the \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{} that you give is doing)?  I would have thought it would mean that Arabic script comes out left-to-right in bookmarks, but I can't see any diff in the output.